# How to call a Class through RequestDispatcher from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forward

I have made a class `RedirectManager` which has a method `doRedirect(request, response, url)` and its role is to forward to specified url (a String argument) using `RequestDispatcher` method `forward()`. I want that on clicking a link on JSP page, (consider an existing) object of `RedirectManager`  calls `doRedirect(url)`.

How to call this method on clicking of a link?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do that (I guess) is sending an http GET request from your link, like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<a href="./MyJspAction?targetUrl=page.html">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

this JSP will send a request to a servlet

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyJspAction
 */
@WebServlet("/MyJspAction")
public class MyJspAction extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String targetUrl = request.getParameter("targetUrl");
        new RedirectManager().doRedirect(request,response,targetUrl);
    }
}
```

then the servlet calls your RedirectManager object

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RedirectManager {

    public void doRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String targetUrl) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher(targetUrl).forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

sending the request to page.html

```
<html>
Hello
</html>
```

Notice that [forward and redirect are different things](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).